# Declare and define in header file, but using preprocessor and include of header in cpp?

Tags: c++

Today i came across some wired code and i would like to know if this has any pro's or con's to be used (i was really confused, so for me this is sort of a no go ;))

And no, i do not seek for opinions, i want to know what that could improve or deprove(?).

myclass.h:

```
#pragma once

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    // other function declarations
private:
#ifdef DEF
   int _var;
#endif
};

#ifdef DEF
MyClass::MyClass():_var(0)
{
    // code goes here
}
// definition of the other member functions
#endif
```

myclass.cpp:

```
#include "def.h"
```

def.h

```
#define DEF
#include "myclass.h"
```

Comment: You want opinions but no opinions? In my opinion, you are confused...

Comment: maybe someone has experience with this sort of practice

Comment: This is very bad practice and can lead to strange bugs if DEF is not consistent in your includes. Not sure what the point of the constructor is.

Comment: You don't want opinions?  Too bad -- this is gross.

Comment: @NeilKirk i only used the constructor as examle to avoid 500 lines of code here, but it should show what is going on

Comment: @Zaiborg Not really. Put functions in the source file. If it needs to be in header file for some reason, mark inline.

Answer (score 2):

Conditionally declaring the private data member is definitely wrong - it means the class will have a different definition (and indeed a different size and layout) in different translation units.

Conditionally defining functions is weird and error-prone, but not intrinsically wrong as long as it is only defined in a single translation unit (as seems to be the case here, if only one file includes `"def.h"`). More conventional would be to put the definition in the source file, or define it `inline` in the header.

Answer (score 1):

The header does not support use in multiple translation units, since its implementation of the constructor is not declared `inline`.

That's like, a definitive con.

The `const` member `_var` is not defined, which means the code will probably not link. That's a bummer.

The use of a prefix underscore convention can lead programmers to do that for things in the global namespace, where it's prohibited. Best avoid that convention. Ungood.

The use of preprocessor symbol to include or exclude a data member is fragile, since it can lead to different class definitions in different translation units. It's also problematic wrt. maintenance. What to replace it with depends much on what it's intended to solve.

Comment: woops. sorry, the const was a mistake of mine. thanks for the tip with the underscore convention :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the practice of including/excluding lines of code depending on some options. It can be useful for OS dependent parts. It is also useful to define options for a specific file; for example [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) uses it [as follows](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#writing-tests):

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN  // This tells Catch to provide a main() - only do this in one cpp file
#include "catch.hpp"
```

to define which translation unit should contain the `main` function.